# Using Custom Login for forms authentication in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, authorize-attribute

I have created an web application with MVC template.I have created a custom view -Login.cshtml .

**Login.cshtml**(View)

```
       @using(Html.BeginForm())
      {
        <div id="Email">
            @Html.Label("UserName")
            @Html.TextBox("user")
        </div>
        <div id="Password">
            @Html.Label("Password")
            @Html.TextBox("password")
        </div>
        <input id="LoginBtn" type="submit" value="Login" />
      }
```

In my controller method if i use [authorize] attribute,it takes me to /Accounts/Login by default which is already available in the template.

**MyController**(Controller)

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Start()
    {
       return View();
    }
```

I need the authentication view as Login.cshtml. So, I tried adding the forms authentication in Configuration file (web.config)

**Web.Config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="xyz" loginUrl="http://localhost:2680/My/Login">
    <credentials>
      <user name="abc" password="pass123" />
    </credentials> 
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Even after adding it , the Accounts/Login ran instead of My/login.

So my question is how to use a custom view for login when we specify [authorize] attribute in controller methods?

Comment: Try Changing the LoginPath property in your App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

Comment: Can u share how to set credentials for this custom view?

Comment: Do you mean Rendering Login View with prefilled values ?

Comment: @AjinderSingh Add it as an answer. :)

Comment: @hutchonoid - Done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Changing the **LoginPath** property in your "App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs"